# Folder not allowed to Rename a sub-folder or delete a non empty-sub-folder while the parent folder is being watched using Chokidar

Tags: node.js, electron, rename, working-directory, chokidar

While watching folder which has subfolders using Chokidar，The watch folder cannot be renamed.

Versions:
    Chokidar version: 3.5.2
    Angular CLI: 12.0.2
    Node: 16.17.0
    Package Manager: npm 9.2.0
    OS version: Windows 10

```js
//defaultOptions for chokidar :
defaultOptions = {
            ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../, // ignore dotfiles
            persistent: true,
            depth: 99,
            alwaysStat: true,
            awaitWriteFinish: {
                stabilityThreshold: 2000,
                pollInterval: 100
            },
            ignorePermissionErrors: false,
            atomic: true // or a custom 'atomicity delay', in milliseconds (default 100)
        }
```

Step 1 : Watch any folder, say Test 1 using chokidar.

Step 2 : Created another folder inside Test 1 say Test 2

Step 3 : Trying renaming Test 2

Step 4 : You should see a Windows prompt "Folder in use" and "The action can't be completed because the folder or file in it is open in another application.

[image]
 
we have observed below thing as well, we thing root cause would be the same that would **folder permissions** or **folder in use**.

**NOTE : Similarly if the sub-folder is non empty ,User is not allowed to delete it and User get prompt "Folder Access Denied" and You'll need to provide administrator permission to delete this folder.**

[image]

we found some useful links in chokidar forum on Github, below are the links.

https://github.com/Bistard/nota/issues/149

https://github.com/hoperyy/sync-directory/issues/53

https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/664

Comment: Same issue, a workaround is to set usePolling: true but for me it's not acceptable. Were you able to find a solution ?